# View jumps when navigation bar is hidden/shown

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

when our labels are in view. Does any one know how can we fix the jump issue when we hide and show navigation bar. I tried lot of things it is not working. Finally I added a layout constraint for my top label and I am giving constant number not to jump it worked but this constant number is not working for other devices. Can any one help me either for fixing view jumping or how can I set the top constraint dynamically so that it won’t be issue in other devices.

Comment: Any chance you could be more specific? Something maybe with code? Something that we could duplicate? In order to help, it really does help if you can be specific about the issue.

Comment: I don’t know how to attach my local project in stack over flow. Steps are : I just created a vc with story board which as a label and 2 buttons when I am loading that VC I need the navigation bar to be animated. So for that I am just doingself.navigationcontroller?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:true) in view will appear and I wrote self.navigationcontroller?.setNavigationBaraHidden(false.”,animated: true) in view did appear. That’s it. When I load the screen before the animation starts my top label is going up for 44 Pxs and when my navigation bar appears then it sets to normal.

Comment: I just wanted to know is their is any way that we can fix this issue. So that my view doesn’t jump when I hide and show navigation bar with the animation. I guess my above comments helps you understand my steps that I am facing the issue for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get that constant number as a ratio instead of hardcoded number. For example lets say your constraint is called as `viewTopConstraint` and then you update it's constant by 10% of your view as:

```
viewTopConstraint.constant += self.view.frame.size.height/10
```

Which would always update the constraint constant for the current device. You should not have a problem device vice. Of course you should try the value to find out what percentage works for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer I am trying to set the top constraint to the top label in the story board. I am setting constant value 184 in view will appear when I am hiding navigation bar and releasing my constant and setting back to normal as 124 in view did appear when I show navigation bar back. So this way it fixed jump issue in iPhone & iPhone plus devices the only issue I found is on iPhone X & iPhone SE so I may try your solution will see if that works.

Comment: print (self.view.frame.size.height) in the devices which is working, and then get the ratio of 184 and 124 respectively with the device's height, and then apply that ratio. After that it should be fine for iPhone X and SE as well.

Comment: Also just to ask do you know how can we fix the jump of view when we hide / show navigation bar .i mean with out adding constraints.

Comment: self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

Try like this, it might not jump if "animated" is set to false.

Comment: I need animation. I want the navigation bar to be animated that’s when I am facing this jump issue. I setting animated true

Comment: you might wanna try animating constraint change in viewWillLayoutSubviews method. It might work but Im not sure